# jquery hover on first image in class

Tags: jquery, hover, css-selectors

I want to toggle images/text for a div class on hover.

```
<div class="fif">
  <img src="img/img1.jpg">
  <div id="pmask">
     some text or image 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fif">
  <img src="img/img2.jpg">
  <div id="pmask">
     some text or image 2
  </div>
</div>
```

So when I hover over "fif", the image is replaced with the content of "pmask".
I've tried:

```
$(".fif").hover(function(){
        // in
        // fadeout image                
        $( "this img:first-child" ).fadeOut("fast");
        // fade in pmask
        $( "this .pmask" ).fadeIn("fast");

  },function(){
    // out
        // fadeout pmask
        $( "this .pmask:first-child" ).fadeOut("fast");
        // fade in image         
        $( "this img" ).fadeIn("fast");     

});
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: And also regarding first-child. You would need to revisit `.pmask:first-child` since `.pmask` is not the first child of the div. And another issue with id against class in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (no pun intended):

```
$(this).find("img:first-child").fadeOut('fast');
```

You can't pass the `this` pointer as a part of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks is because the way you are binding `this`, this is an oject and can't be bind as a string as long as i know. Why dont you try:

```
$(".fif").hover(function(){
        // in
        // fadeout image                
        $(this).find("img").fadeOut("fast");
        // fade in pmask
        $( this ).find(".pMask").fadeIn("fast");

  },function(){
    // out
        // fadeout pmask
        $(this).find(".pMask").fadeOut("fast");
        // fade in image         
        $(this).find("img")fadeIn("fast");     

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$('.pmask').hide();
$(".fif").hover(function(){
        // in
        // fadeout image                
        $(this).children("img").fadeOut("fast");
        // fade in pmask
        $(this).children(".pmask").fadeIn("fast");

  },function(){
    // out
        // fadeout pmask
        $(this).children(".pmask").fadeOut("fast");
        // fade in image         
        $(this).children("img").fadeIn("fast");     

});
```

And for the `html`, I changed your `#pmask` id's to `.pmask` class.

```
<div class="fif">
  <img src="img/img1.jpg">
  <div class="pmask">
     some text or image 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fif">
  <img src="img/img2.jpg">
  <div class="pmask">
     some text or image 2
  </div>
</div>
```

here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4QF4C/37/